Prove that $ \sum_{n = 0 }^\infty \frac{\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})}{n+1}$ is convergent.
So I've tried to show that the series is convergent with a help of Dirichlet's theroem
$\sum_{n = 0 }^\infty \frac{\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})}{n+1}$, but it turned out that the following sum diverges
$\sum_{n = 0 }^\infty \cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3}) $
$\sum_{n = 0 }^\infty \cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3}) = 1,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},1,...$ and so on.
I also checked the necessary conditon
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})}{n+1}= 0 $
After showing the convergence of this series I should calculate the sum with a help of the following power series (that was also a hint to this exercise)
$\sum_{n = 0 }^\infty \frac{\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})}{n+1}x^{n+1}$
this part seems to be relatively easy but to take the derivative of the sum I ought to know the radius of the power series and that comes down to calculating (probably) another limit...
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{\cos(\frac{2(n+1)\pi}{3})}{n+1}}{\frac{\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})}{n+2}}= \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n+2}{n+1})\frac{\cos(\frac{2(n+1)\pi}{3})}{\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})} = ...$

Don't use multi-line Latex for your titles

Eventhough the cosine series diverges, it is bounded. Dirichlet's Test only uses the fact that it is bounded and does not care if the series converges or diverges.

Yes, use Dirichlet's test. Showing the partial sums of cosine are bounded will be much easier if you know that cosine is the real part of complex exponential.

In such a simple case, all this seems overkill. $\frac{\cos\frac{2n\pi}3}{n+1}\to0$ and
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\cos\frac{2n\pi}3}{n+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{3k+1}-\frac{1/2}{3k+2}-\frac{1/2}{3k+3}\right)\&=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{9k+7}{(3k+1)(3k+2)(3k+3)}<\infty.
\end{align}$$

@AnneBauval This was my first idea too but Mark observed that in this way we were considering a partial sum for an alternating series and therefore the method was wrong.

@user Actually, I guess it can be turned into a correct proof, but you need to explain why the other subsequences tend to the same limit. It indeed follows from the general term tending to $0$, which Anne Bauval mentioned, but it has to be verified. In a calculus exam, I wouldn't accept such a solution without a detailed proof.

@Mark Thanks for this detailed explanation and for the previous comment.

We have that
$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{3}\right)}{n+1}= \Re\left(\frac{e^{i\frac{2n\pi}{3}}}{n+1}\right)$$
then since by geometric series
$$\sum_{n = 0 }^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+1}=-\frac{1}{x}\log(1-x)$$
we have
$$\sum_{n = 0 }^\infty \frac{\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})}{n+1}=\Re\left(
\sum_{n = 0 }^\infty
\frac{e^{i\frac{2n\pi}{3}}}{n+1}\right)=\Re\left(-e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}\log\left(1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}\right)\right)=\frac{\log 3}4+\frac{\sqrt 3 \pi}{12}$$

@Mark Yes of course! Thanks

@Winther Yeah, it should be with finite sums. The sequence of partial sums is bounded.

@Winther Yes, I delete this part! this is uncorrect! Thanks

You can use Dirichlet's test. In order to apply it, you need to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{3} \right)$ is less than some fixed $M\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $n$.  This is easy since, as you mention, the series has a simple pattern. In fact, one can even show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\left(a+k\cdot d \right)$ is bounded. This is not too hard to do thanks to the following formula: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos (a+k \cdot d) =\frac{\sin(n \times \frac{d}{2})}{\sin ( \frac{d}{2} )} \times \cos \biggl( \frac{ 2 a + (n-1)\cdot d}{2}\biggr).$$
You can find a proof of the formula here.

In fact the partial sums are trivially $1,1/2,0,1,1/2,0,\dots$.
